# Outlook 2010 Cached Exchange Mode setting registry location?

Tags: outlook, exchange-2010, windows-registry, outlook-2010

What is the Registry setting to disable Cached Exchange Mode for Outlook 2010?

It does not appear to be the same as the [Outlook 2003 key](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/cachedmoderegkey.htm) (13dbb0c8aa05101a9bb000aa002fc45a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way is different, you can configure it by [this guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179175.aspx)

EDIT: I just found this, it might work with these settings, can't check it though:

Cached Exchange Mode is controlled by the following key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\d4c3fff326ad1c498c9982bc456d4c6a]

00036601     (REG_BINARY)
enabled value;  84 19 00 00
enabled with Public Folders/Favorites: 84 05 00 00
disabled value; 04 10 00 00
```

As seen on: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/c8b06311-3036-4d51-a028-3ee58ac536fd

Comment: Thanks - so the only way to disable it if Outlook won't load is through group policy?

Comment: Thanks again. Turned out a product called ShoreTel Agent was causing issues with Outlook. We killed that task and could then get into Outlook to change the settings.